# Should I bother my colleagues with indentation?

Tags: coding-style

My colleagues use a 4-spaces indentation style on a JavaScript project. I personnaly prefer a 2-spaces indentation for JS.

Should I bother them with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general I think it is a good habit to discuss and finalize a common code style guideline in the project team. Like that, you are able to work more efficiently in the team and you can avoid merging troubles caused by auto-formatter when using version control systems as Git.

Also for your specific case I would recommend to discuss it and come to an agreement for a common guideline. However, most version control systems are able to ignore the indents when comparing files, so it would not have a that big impact there.